# Micronaut-Data issue with custom datasource

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I have create sample project with custom datasource

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demo
datasources:
  customerDS:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./DATA/devDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2
jpa.customerDS.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

Also created repository interface as follows

```
@Repository ("customerDS")
public interface CustomerRepository
        extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

**The project is hosted in github**
https://github.com/micro-service-projects/demo-custom-datasourceName

**When i run the application and access the endpoint getting error as follows:**

> curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/customer {"message":"Internal Server
> Error: Error instantiating bean of type
> [com.example.CustomerController]: No backing RepositoryOperations
> configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again"}

**Console error message as follows:**

> gradle clean run

> Task :compileJava Note: Creating bean classes for 3 type elements

> Task :run 15:56:12.552 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 1494ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080 15:56:26.239 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.CustomerController]: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.CustomerController]: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1918)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2635)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2621)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2296) at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.access$100(DefaultBeanContext.java:78)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:426)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:469)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:255)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$9(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1352)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDefer.subscribeActual(FlowableDefer.java:35)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14882)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.context.ServerRequestContextFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(ServerRequestContextFilter.java:62)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14885)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildExecutableRoute$5(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1056)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultUriRouteMatch$1.execute(DefaultUriRouteMatch.java:80)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:686)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:548)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:143)
> at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:197) at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:191)
> at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:153)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:124)
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:78)
> at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
> at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:106)
> at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
> at com.example.CustomerRepository$Intercepted.save(Unknown Source)
> at com.example.CustomerController.postSample(CustomerController.java:23)
> at com.example.$CustomerControllerDefinition.initialize(Unknown Source)
> at com.example.$CustomerControllerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1889)
> ... 82 common frames omitted Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('customerDS'). Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2281)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:716)
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:119)
> ... 91 common frames omitted 16:12:11.044 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.CustomerController]: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [com.example.CustomerController]: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1918)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingletonInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2635)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:2621)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:2296) at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.access$100(DefaultBeanContext.java:78)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.getTarget(DefaultBeanContext.java:426)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:469)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:255)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$9(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1352)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDefer.subscribeActual(FlowableDefer.java:35)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14882)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.context.ServerRequestContextFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(ServerRequestContextFilter.java:62)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromPublisher.subscribeActual(FlowableFromPublisher.java:29)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14935)
> at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:14885)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildExecutableRoute$5(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1056)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultUriRouteMatch$1.execute(DefaultUriRouteMatch.java:80)
> at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:118)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:686)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:548)
> at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:143)
> at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:197) at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:191)
> at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:153)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321) at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
> at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: No backing RepositoryOperations configured for repository. Check your configuration and try again
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:124)
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:78)
> at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
> at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:106)
> at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:69)
> at com.example.CustomerRepository$Intercepted.save(Unknown Source)
> at com.example.CustomerController.postSample(CustomerController.java:23)
> at com.example.$CustomerControllerDefinition.initialize(Unknown Source)
> at com.example.$CustomerControllerDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1889)
> ... 82 common frames omitted Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.data.operations.PrimaryRepositoryOperations] exists for the given qualifier: @Named('customerDS'). Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2281)
> at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:716)
> at io.micronaut.data.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.findInterceptor(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:119)
> ... 91 common frames omitted <==========---> 80% EXECUTING [24m 44s]
> :run

Comment: Did you find any solution for this one?